# Is every odd prime a divisor of a Mersenne number $M_q$ with $q$ prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be an odd prime number.

*Question*: Is there a prime number $q$ such that $p$ divides $2^q-1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, for example let $p=5$. Then $p$ divides $2^q-1$ if and only if $q\equiv 0\bmod 4$.

Comment: I see, so in general if $r$ is a generator of the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^*$, then $n$ divides $r^m-1$ iff $φ(n)$ divides $m$.

Comment: What are the prime numbers $p$ such that $2$ generates the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/p)^*$ ?

Comment: @Sébastien: We can't really answer those kinds of questions yet. For example, we don't even know if there are infinitely many such $p$ yet. See Artin's conjecture: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots